# Fit K-nearest neighbors mod w/n_neighbors using distance for weights

Tags: knn

Fit K-nearest neighbors mod w/n_neighbors using distance for weights
-Calculate acc -Fit K-nearest neighbors mod using unif. weights, set pwr param for minkowski dist metric to be 1 (p=1)

#Student writes code here

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, weights='distance')
```

#code error: could not convert string to float KS

```
knn = knn.fit(X_data, y_data)
```

#Can you please help me format the code to accept the float please below

```
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table))
dfs[0] = dfs[0].iloc[:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data = tabulate(dfs[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')
```